# where i can change the words of Newsletter in Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

i am very new of Magento2, I saw in the "page" that this form should be used to call out the newsletter form :

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe"                          
        name="static.newsletter"       
        template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```

But I would like to change the words of this form, or add more words there. I have already tried looking for in the system but didn't find it and I dont know where to change it. Does anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches for changing words inside that form.

- If you want to change this form for everywhere on your Magento system, you can override it inside your theme.
  `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml`
- If you want to change this form to a specific page, you can create your own template and assign it.